# In what path I can find the .crt file for Let's Encrypt SSL?

Tags: https, security-certificate, configuration, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to find the SSL .crt file that was installed on my Ubuntu server using Let's Encrypt.
I used this commands below for installing Let's Encrypt free SSL:

```
$sudo apt-get update 
$sudo apt-get install python-letsencrypt-apache
$sudo letsencrypt --apache -d example.com
```

Comment: Sorry but you will need to edit your question and include more information. You will need to tell us how it was originally installed and what operating system you use. CRT files locations vary from depending on the Linux or Windows version being used, furthermore cPanel and Plesk also have their own file paths that differ too, more information needed before people can help you.

Comment: @SimonHayter I followed this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: No links please, edit your question and include that information... people should be able to answer your question without having to click external sites. But to add we don't need the full tutorial. Just simplify the process you did a in a few paragraphs, from that we can answer your question. For example, I installed the Let's Encrypt using `sudo letsencrypt --apache -d example.com` where does it store the SSL cert?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After successfully running Lets Encrypt for example.com, the *latest* certificate files can be found in the following location:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
```

- *cert.pem*: The private certificate for your domain
- *chain.pem*: The Let's Encrypt "chain" certificate that needs to be installed with the private domain certificate
- *fullchain.pem*: *cert.pem* and *chain.pem* concatenated
- *privkey.pem*: The private key for *cert.pem*

Answer (score 6):

### Quick Answer

```
ubuntu: 
/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem (Certificate)
/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem (Private Key)
```

---

### Details

You are looking for file like cert.crt, actually letsencrypt uses cert.pem for your certificate and privkey.pem for private key.
So they always use .pem extension which can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that the file for which you are looking will be there, but [Let's Encrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Encrypt) puts files in `/etc/letsencrypt/`. If you have the mlocate package installed, then you can use `locate .crt` to find all .crt files on the system. If you don't, you can run `find / -name *.crt` from the root account, though locating all files with the `find` command will be slower than with the [locate command](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/centos/7/man/locate.php), though the `locate` command won't find the file if the database it uses hasn't been updated by `updatedb` since the relevant file was placed on the system; the [updatedb command](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/centos/7/man/updatedb.php) is usually run once daily by [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: Let's encrypt will use `.pem` file extensions rather than `.crt` on Ubuntu for Apache.